# An exception when downloading an image from url to siverlight c# project

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, windows-desktop-gadgets

I searched how to make a gadget for windows 7/vista programmatically in c# , at the end I downloaded a visual studio solution called SilverLightGadgetDebugger:

> The purpose of the SilverlightGadgetDebugger project is only to act as
>   a debug session starter for the
>               Silverlight gadget. Even though it is a console application project, it produces no output.
>               Instead, whenever the project is started it will invoke the SidebarSandboxStarter.exe file.
>               This application receives the current solution path as a command line parameter. 
>               It uses this information to connect to the Visual Studio that has the specified solution opened.
>               The SidebarSandboxStarter will attach the debugger from that instance of Visual Studio to the Windows Sidebar
>               process (sidebar.exe). If the process is not started, it will start it.

I added an Image silverlight control, I'm trying to get the image from this url :

```
http://lunaf.com/images/moon-phases/lunar_phase_20.jpg
```

I searched how to get the image , I tried this code :

```
private void DownloadImage()
{
        string ImagePath = "http://lunaf.com/images/moon-phases/lunar_phase_20.jpg";
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.OpenReadCompleted += client_OpenReadCompleted;

        if (ImagePath.IndexOf("http") < 0)
        {
            string URL = System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.AbsoluteUri;
            ImagePath = URL.Substring(0, URL.LastIndexOf('/')) + "/" + ImagePath;
        }

        client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(ImagePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), ImagePath);

    }

    void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            BitmapImage ImageToLoad = new BitmapImage();
            ImageToLoad.SetSource(e.Result as Stream);//Here is the exception
            Image1.Source = ImageToLoad;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
}
```

I get an exception , its message (ex.message) :

> An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.
>   Check InnerException for exception details.

And the inner exception :

```
{System.Security.SecurityException ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndGetResponse>b__9(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.WebClient.OpenReadAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult result)}
```

how to fix that ??

Comment: What did the InnerException say?

Comment: nothing,it is empty ""

Comment: which line is giving error

Comment: I added a comment next to it

Comment: sorry @DGibbs I added the inner exception ..

Comment: @KaramNajjar [lmgtfy](http://bit.ly/1sOQPmq)